# Laptop randomly freezes

Tags: windows-7, laptop, freeze

I need some help as my laptop a few months ago started to freeze totally randomly, when it freezes it repeats the last sound it made with distortion, the mouse and keyboard stop responding without allowing me to turn on the shift lock light, and the disk light stops blinking.

This in itself is something old and at the time I thought it was a RAM card problem so I replaced it and the error calmed down for a while since the only fixed way to freeze it was disconnecting it from the charger (I work with the laptop always connected since the battery is damaged and it turns off in a short time) but recently I had to disconnect it and it started to freeze again randomly and when I disconnect it from the charger.

Comment: At your own risk, if it were me i would open that bad boy up and vacuum it clean. It's really unorthodox but I like to take my hardware outside and I use my garden leaf blower to really blast the dust out of it (a cold setting on a good hair dryer takes longer but also does the trick). I'd then buy new ram sticks and double the capacity of the ram.

Comment: I should add, often a clean windows installation from scratch + full updates fixes these issues if you're willing to copy off your important data and do this. I would do this first before investing in more ram sticks. That said, i have seen freezing and crashing from machines being hammered by memory intensive tasks.

Comment: @Mastaxx - If you have an answer, can you put it in the answer space, not in comments, especially as there is already an answer here. Insisting yours should be read first without being voted on just says "I'm more important than anyone else & my answer deserves to be at the top."

Comment: @Tetsujin - I don't have an answer. Only a comment. I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

"repeats the last sound it made with distortion"
Classic symptom of *two* different things - overheat &/or under-power.

You'll need to take it apart to clean it to prevent the overheat; but you'll probably also need to replace the battery to prevent under-power. The charger alone can't keep up.

Comment: I forgot totally about this, i gotta thanks you cuz the problem is solved now it was the battery indeed

Comment: The first few days as I could not find a battery model that would fit my laptop I worked with the laptop without the battery but with the charger even though it would suddenly shut down the first time I turned it on when I restarted it, it was fully functional.

Comment: I now have a new battery and it works very well.